# getting the first n elements of a specified char array arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, char, arduino-uno

My aim is reading some string from serial for example 234124!3455addg#5867 if the program sees ! it should start to add it to a char array and if it sees # it should return the first 4 elements of that char array for my example the return should be 3455. How can I solve it? I made this using String class but I need to implement it to char array.
I am quite new on arduino so please be clear thank you. 
Here is my code:

```
const char *s = "123123123!0037selam#aaaaSDSDa";
const char *CHAR1 = "!";
const char *CHAR2 = "#";

char *target = NULL;
char *start, *end;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if ( start = strstr( s, CHAR1 ) )
    {
        start += strlen( CHAR1 );
        if ( end = strstr( start, CHAR2 ) )
        {
            target = ( char * )malloc( end - start + 1 );
            memcpy( target, start, end - start );
            target[end - start] = '\0';
        }
    }

    if ( target )
    {
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
            Serial.print( target[i]);
    }

    free( target );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have provided some code but you have not explained what issue you have with it. And note that Arduino uses C++ not C.

Comment: My issue is it is not working totally. I cannot make anything meaningful so I asked the quesiton for a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler way of going about it, I think. It depends on whether or not there are requirements that aren't explicitly stated.

A few things worth mentioning,

1. You'd like to return the first 4 bytes that follow a '!', so you
   only need to buffer 4 chars
2. I haven't got all the cables handy at the moment, so I've just
   banged-together something to run on the PC. In your case, instead of
   returning a copy of the string buffer you'd just output it with
   Serial.print

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class dummy
{
    public:
        dummy()
        {
            const char *testData = "234124!3455addg#5867";
            int dataLen = strlen(testData);
            mData = new char[dataLen+1];
            strcpy(mData, testData);
            mTotal = strlen(testData);
            mIndex = 0;
        }
        int available()
        {
            return mTotal - mIndex;
        }
        char read()
        {
            return mData[mIndex++];
        }
    private:
        char *mData;
        int mIndex;
        int mTotal;
};

char *testFunc()
{
    dummy *Serial = new dummy();
/// -------- 8< ------------ cut here until the next pair of scissors. put inside the loop function
/// your code does all of the functionality (reading and buffering) inside a single iteration of loop(). 
/// Normally, I'd expect a single character to be read each time. I'd expect loop() to be 
/// run 16 times before a result was output, since # is the 16th character of the string.
    char tmpBuffer[5] = {0};
    int bufferIndex = 0;
    bool marker1Seen = false;

    while (Serial->available() > 0)
    {
        char received = Serial->read();
        if (received == '!')
        {
            marker1Seen = true;
        }

        else if (received == '#')
        {
            return strdup(tmpBuffer);
        }

        else if (marker1Seen == true && bufferIndex < 4)
        {
            tmpBuffer[bufferIndex++] = received;
        }
    }
    // shouldn't get here if the input is well-formed
    return NULL;
/// -------- 8< ------------ cut here
}

int main()
{
    char *result = testFunc();
    cout << result;
    delete result;
}
```

Comment: So which part should be inside the loop and which part should be inside the setup. As I said I am quite new on this.

Comment: Of course, sorry. I'll edit the code with some comments. Just give me a minute or so. I've only tried to replicate the functionality of the `loop()` function.

Comment: then how can I print the result?

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61143922/returning-different-parts-of-a-char-array-arduino)  I posted another question about this topic can you help me

Answer (score 0):

I followed your code and I did some changes to behave as your example.

If your string is always such that, where the `!` always come before the `#` and, in between them there will always be some numbers to work on, then you can do some loops to wait for those markers.

So, basically:

- loop to keep checking the receiving of a `!` mark;
- loop to keep checking for valid digits with `isdigit()` function;
- loop to look for the closing mark, the `#`

But again, this algorithm works with the example you provided.

```c
 #define MAXSIZE (200)

    char Tmp[MAXSIZE];

    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        Serial.println("Enter a Message");
    }
    void loop() {
        int counter, i;
        char received;

        while (Serial.available() <= 0) {
          /* keep in the loop*/
        }

        while (Serial.read() != '!') {
            /* keep waiting the '!' */
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (isdigit((received = Serial.read())) == 0)
                break;
            Tmp[counter++] =  received;
            delay(10);
        }
        while (Serial.read() != '#') {
            /* keep waiting the '!' */
        }
        Tmp[counter] = 0;

        Serial.write(Tmp, strlen(Tmp));

        newPack(Tmp);

        // after you are done, make sure to clean up
        // your buffer for the next round
        counter = 0;
        memset(Tmp, 0, MAXSIZE);
    }
```

Also, I noticed you are returning at the end of the `loop()` function.
You are not supposed to do that because embedded systems like Arduino must have an infinite loop to keep running.

Comment: It did not work. There should be Serial.print() in somewhere

Comment: Could you be more specific then what is your problem? I did not understand.

Comment: when I enter 234124!3455addg#5867 the program should return 3455 but your code does not make anything when I run it

Comment: Let's make question more understandable. I want to get chars between two chracters which are ! and # firstly

Comment: I edited to print it to the serial what it has stored in `Tmp`. `Tmp` is the one that is keeping the numbers you are looking for.