# How to store serial inputs in an char array arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, serial-port

My aim was getting some parts of a char array between 2 specified characters. The code below perfectly works and returns 0037 as I expected. However I wanted to make it useable with serial input not only char*s. In other words if I write "123123123!0037sjd#asdasdasd" to the serial, the code should work in a same way again.

How can I do that?

```
const char *s = "123123123!0037sjd#asdasdasd";
const char *CHAR1 = "!";
const char *CHAR2 = "#";
char *target = NULL;
char *start, *end;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  //s=(char)Serial.read();
  if (start = strstr(s, CHAR1)) {
    start += strlen(CHAR1);
    if (end = strstr(start, CHAR2)) {
      target = (char*) malloc(end - start + 1);
      memcpy(target, start, end - start);
      target[end - start] = '\0';
    }
  }
  if (target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Serial.print(target[i]);
    }
    target = "";
    free(target);
  }
  target = "";
  free(target);
}
```

Comment: To use the code you already have, you'll need to store the received bytes in a `char` buffer, you'll need to append a null terminator (search term: "c-style string"), you'll need to define the maximum length of bytes you may receive on the serial, you'll need to define how your program knows that a byte sequence on the serial is over (an end character, writing the length as the first byte, or just waiting for the read operation to timeout), and you'll need to define what your program does if it receives a byte sequence longer than it can handle. After that you can use the code you have.

Comment: Could you possibly edit my code in this way?Because I am quite new on this. I have to use char array not string.

Comment: Why do you have to use char array and not `String` or `std::string`?

Comment: My first comment described defining a protocol. It doesn't start with code. It starts with pen and paper. You need to design the rules of communication between your computer and the arduino. Only after you define those rules can you implement them (code them). The rule could be as simple as "The computer will only ever send exactly 10 characters," but you still need the rule. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: A "c-style string" is just a null-terminated array of characters.

Comment: So is there any way to do that work without using String class?

Comment: yes, by storing the data in a `char` buffer. Something like `char serial_buf[100];` But without knowing the protocol you want to use I can't help you beyond that. Again - you need to know the protocol you're using BEFORE you start coding. In practice you can code a little, find out your limitations, define the protocol a little, have a question about what's easy to do with the code, code a little more, adjust the protocol a little more. It can be iterative, especially if you have no experience.

Comment: You can take advantage of the `Serial::readBytes` and `Serial::readBytesUntil` functions depending on what protocol you want to go with: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytesuntil/

Comment: What dou u mean by protocol?

Comment: You duplicated your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120228/getting-the-first-n-elements-of-a-specified-char-array-arduino/61120511?noredirect=1#comment108130271_61120511).

Comment: @Redux I just mean the rules of communication between two devices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol

Answer (score 0):

Assignment loses original allocation.

Code errantly free's something not allocated.

```
// Bad
target="";        // loses prior allocation
free( target );   // Attempts to free something not allocated
```

Instead

```
free( target );
target = NULL;
```

Comment: When I write like that, 0037 goes infinitely

Comment: @ReduXCompletedy LIkely you have only applied this fix to 1 of 2 places in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing a serial stream like that, maybe just use a flag. Start off with the flag cleared. When you see a *!* set the flag. When digits come in while the flag is set, store them in the array. When you see something that's not a digit, clear the flag.

You could even accumulate the digits in an integer on the fly (skipping the array), if that's what the end result will be.

Personally, I don't use malloc/free on the Arduino, and it's not really needed here.

HTH!