# Returning different parts of a char array arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120228/getting-the-first-n-elements-of-a-specified-char-array-arduino/61121144?noredirect=1#comment108130521_61121144) about my issue and thanks to @enhzflep I solved the huge part of my problem. My problem was if I write 46754!ABCDEFG12345#qwerwe to the serial, I want to get AB which is two chars after '!'. The code below does this work perfectly. However now I need to get 'CD', 'EF', three chars before '#' (for my example it means '345') and the whole thing between these things which is 'G12' the size of 'G12' depends on the size of the whole thing between '!' and '#'. In short I want to get different parts of the char array between '!' and '#'.

```
char pack[5] = {0};
char command[5] ={0};
int Index = 0;
bool Seen = false;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){  
    while (Serial.available() > 0){
        char received = Serial.read();
        if (received == '!')
        {
            Seen = true;
        }
        else if (received == '#')
        {
            return strdup(pack);
            return strdup(command);
        }
        else if (Seen == true){ 
            if(Index<2){

                pack[Index++] = received;
                Serial.print(received);
            }
            /*if(Index>2&&Index<5){
                command[Index++] = received;
                Serial.print(received);
            }  */
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: What's the result you are currently getting?

Comment: I get AB as I expected. However I need to get CD, EF, 3 chars before # and the whole thing between them. This code only returns n chars after ! depending on what I write inside the if(Index<n)

Comment: Is the length known?

Comment: no it depends on what I write to the serial. but only the length of 'G12'(As I mentioned above) changes other things's length are known.

Comment: Is there a maximum size? I'm just wondering if you're going to want to dynamically allocated memory for storing the command.

Comment: Yes there can be maximum size lets say 200 chars

Comment: Hmmm. This and the question linked in the description seem to be a wonderful example of the X/Y problem phenomenon.  That is to say, you have a problem, Y. You think that in order to solve it, you'll need to do X. So, you post a question asking for help to solve X. The answer does this, but then you discover that X doesn't solve Y, so you then think Z will solve Y and then ask how to solve Z. Often, the correct answer to "how do I Z?" doesn't help much either. So, I'm just going to ask as I should have in the last one, "What are you actually trying to do? What's the ultimate aim/purpose?"

Answer (score 0):

I can't test any code myself, but I think this should work. Change the allocation of `command` to 200 bytes. Your commented out code seemed mostly correct. I just made some minor changes:

```
if(Index>=2){
    command[Index-2] = received;
    Index++;
    Serial.print(received);
}
```

Comment: It did not help

Comment: Could you be more specific about the result?

Comment: I think I need different char arrays for every part of it. for example first 2 elements should be stored in an array, another 2 should be in another array and so on. but I don't know how to do it

Comment: @ReduXCompletedy Why do you think you need to do that? Could you tell me the result with the inputted code?

Comment: it did not print anything

Comment: My code is already prints pack. I need other things to be printed

Comment: @ReduXCompletedy Could you just post the complete output so I can better understand what's going on?